Unable to use dictionary parameters in the right way while sending HTTP requests to a link
I'm attempting to scrape the tabular content from this webpage. I want to display the JSON response received after sending a GET HTTP request with parameters.
When I manually input the parameters as a string from the developer tools and incorporate them directly into the script, I achieve the desired outcome. However, when I attempt to use the parameters as a dictionary, as is the conventional approach, I encounter a status 500 error.
import requests

url = 'https://www.produktdatenbank-get.at/api/products'

# params = {
#     'eq(group)': '337',
#     'eq(instock)': '1',
#     'ne(custom.field_28)': ['R-404A', 'R-407C', 'R-417A', 'R-410A'],
#     'eq(custom.field_133)': '1',
#     'select': 'image,id,name,custom.field_22,custom.field_28,custom.field_133,subsidable,custom.field_78',
#     'sort': '+name'
# }

params = "eq(group,337)&eq(instock,1)&ne(custom.field_28,R-404A)&ne(custom.field_28,R-407C)&ne(custom.field_28,R-417A)&ne(custom.field_28,R-410A)&eq(custom.field_133,1)&select(image,id,name,custom.field_22,custom.field_28,custom.field_133,subsidable,custom.field_78)&sort(+name)"


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'identity',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Host': 'www.produktdatenbank-get.at',
    'Referer': 'https://www.produktdatenbank-get.at/',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

res = requests.get(url,params=params,headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.json())

To be specific, if I execute the script as is, I find success, but I encounter a status 500 error when I uncomment the dictionary params and kick out the params used as a string.
How can I use the dictionary parameters within the script and get a JSON response?

What's the actual URL the request gets made to with the dictionary version? I'd guess it's related to how they're serialised.

Those are not key/value parameters that can be passed as params. The params keyword expects a dictionary of key/value pairs.

The URL is within the script provided.

No, the full URL with the serialised query parameters, using the dictionary version. That's what's failing, right? So have you tried finding out what it is?

You will have to find that API documentation, some parameters can be clearly passed as dictionary e.g. equal can be replaced by dictionary:
params = {
    "group": 337,
    "instock": 1,
}

For non equality and selection you will have to either find it in API description, how to compose it or you can make your own custom parser for that query string:
import requests

url = 'https://www.produktdatenbank-get.at/api/products'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'identity',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Host': 'www.produktdatenbank-get.at',
    'Referer': 'https://www.produktdatenbank-get.at/',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}
params = {
    "eq": {
        "group": 337,
        "instock": 1,
        "custom.field_133": 1,
    },
    "ne": {
        "custom.field_28": ["R-407C", "R-417A", "R-410A"],
    },
    "select": ["image","id","name","custom.field_22","custom.field_28","custom.field_133","subsidable","custom.field_78"],
    "sort": "+name"
}

def makeQueryString(aDict):
    q = ""
    for key, val in aDict.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            if isinstance(val[next(iter(val))], list):
                for k, vals in val.items():
                    q += "&".join([f"{key}({k},{item})" for item in vals])
            else:
                q += "&".join([f"{key}({k},{v})" for k, v in val.items()])
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            q += f'{key}({",".join(val)})'
        else:
            q += f'{key}({val})'
        q += "&"
    return q[:-1]

res = requests.get(url,params=makeQueryString(params),headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.json())

Note: Your selection of custom fields doesn't work as expected.
